# Missing payment to my Monero Core GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I would really appreciate your help in understanding whats happened to a transaction of mine. Ok, so the details:
I used Exodus Wallet to send DASH to Shapeshift, in order to Exchange for Monero.
I have used these guys many times before. This time I was using a Monero address and payment ID of mine, generated by the new Monero Core GUI wallet - (which i downloaded today).

On Shapeshift the transaction said it was completed successfully. I have looked at the DASH transaction from my Exodus wallet to the SS wallet and that is all confirmed okay.

So, I made sure I specified the correct Monero deposit address, and the correct Payment ID as per what was in the Monero receive part of the wallet.

I will point out that all of this was conducted AFTER I had completed fully syncing the wallet to the network.

I've shutdown/restarted the Monero wallet and still the same, no deposit.

I have reported this issue to SS also.

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Can you provide the Monero transaction ID so it can be checked on a block explorer?

Comment: Make sure the blockchain is fully synced this could take some hours the first time you start the wallet(Daemon).

Comment: I am having the same issue as well. I have fully synced to the blockchain and no funds showing up in wallet.

Comment: Blockchain was fully synced before I made the transaction.

Comment: Problem  appears to have been on shapeshift end - they processed the payment manually and all fine now.

Comment: @freedomprivacy can you mark this question as resolved please?